# JavaScript initialization for a personal portfolio website

Tags: javascript, jquery

As this community is full of experienced JavaScript developers, and I'm a newbie in JavaScript, I would like if some of you could look over my code for a website I'm building (personal portfolio) and give some insight on how I can improve it, maybe make it more readable and clean, things I may be doing wrong or I missed.

And here's the JavaScript (excluding plugins and other JavaScript libraries):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var default_cluster_options = {
    environment             : "Development",
    local_storage_key       : "Cluster",
    plugin_navigation_class : ".navigation",
    plugin_wrapper_id       : "content-wrapper",
    headings                : ['.heading-first h1', '.heading-second h1'],
    input_types             : ['input', 'textarea'],
    info_iqns_class         : ".iqn",
    preview_iqn_class       : ".preview",
    limits                  : [ { min: 1224, items: 8 }, { min: 954, items: 6 }, { min: 624, items: 4 }, { min: 0, items: 2 } ],
    shop_local_storage_key  : "Shop",
};

var default_plugin_options = {
    containerID : "",
    first       : false,
    previous    : false,
    next        : false,
    last        : false,
    startPage   : 1,
    perPage     : 1,
    midRange    : 6,
    startRange  : 1,
    endRange    : 1,
    keyBrowse   : false,
    scrollBrowse: false,
    pause       : 0,
    clickStop   : true,
    delay       : 50,
    direction   : "auto",
    animation   : "fadeIn",
    links       : "title",
    fallback    : 1000,
    minHeight   : true,
    callback    : function(pages, items) {}
};

var Cluster = function(cluster_options, plugin_options) {

    var self = this;

    this.options = $.extend({}, default_cluster_options, cluster_options);

    this.plugin_options = $.extend({}, default_plugin_options, plugin_options);

    this.environment = this.options.environment;

    this.data_key = this.options.local_storage_key;

    this.shop_data_key = this.options.shop_local_storage_key;

    this.plugin_navigation_class = this.options.plugin_navigation_class;

    this.plugin_wrapper_id = this.options.plugin_wrapper_id;

    this.headings = this.options.headings;

    this.input_types = this.options.input_types;

    this.viewport = $(window);

    this.body = $('body');

    this.viewport_width = this.viewport.width();

    this.viewport_height = this.viewport.height();

    this.info_iqns_class = this.body.find(this.options.info_iqns_class);

    this.preview_iqn_class = this.body.find(this.options.preview_iqn_class);

    this.limits = this.options.limits;

    this.current_shop_page = this.options.current_shop_page;

    this.total_shop_pages = this.options.total_shop_pages;

    this.initiate_cluster(self.plugin_navigation_class, {
        containerID : self.plugin_wrapper_id,
        startPage : +(self.get_local_storage_data(self.data_key) || 1),
        callback : function(pages){
            self.set_local_storage_data(self.data_key, pages.current);
        }
    });

    this.inititate_shop();

    this.initiate_shop_touch_events();

};

Cluster.prototype.set_environment = function() {
    if(this.environment == "Development") {
        less.env = "development";
        less.watch();
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.set_local_storage_data = function(data_key, data_val) {
    return localStorage.setItem(data_key, data_val);
};

Cluster.prototype.get_local_storage_data = function(data_key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(data_key);
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_scalable_text = function() {
    for(var i in this.headings) {
        $(this.headings[i]).fitText(1.6);
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_placeholder_support = function() {
    for(var i in this.input_types) {
        $(this.input_types[i]).placeholder();
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_iqn_selected_class = function() {
    if(this.viewport_width < 980) {
        $(this.info_iqns_class).each(function(index, element) {
            var iqn = $(element).parent();
            $(iqn).on('click', function() {
                if($(iqn).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(iqn).removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $(iqn).addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_preview_action = function() {
    $(this.preview_iqn_class).each(function(index, element) {
        var data = $(element).attr('data-image-link');
        $(element).on('click', function(ev) {
            $.lightbox(data, {
                'modal'         : true,
                'autoresize'    : true
            });
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
    });
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_plugin = function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, this.plugin_options, plugin_options);
    return $(plugin_navigation).jPages(options);
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_shop_touch_events = function() {
    var self = this;
    return $("#shop-items-wrapper").hammer({prevent_default: true, drag_min_distance: Math.round(this.viewport_width * 0.1)}).bind("drag", function(ev) {
        var data = JSON.parse(self.get_local_storage_data(self.shop_data_key));
        if (ev.direction == "left") {
            var next_page = parseInt(data.current_page + 1);
            if(next_page > 0 && next_page <= data.total_pages) {
                $(".shop-items-navigation").jPages(next_page);
            }
        }
        if(ev.direction == "right") {
            var prev_page = parseInt(data.current_page - 1);
            if(prev_page > 0 && prev_page <= data.total_pages) {
                $(".shop-items-navigation").jPages(prev_page);
            }
        }
    });
}

Cluster.prototype.inititate_shop = function() {
    var self = this;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.limits.length; i++) {
        if(this.viewport_width >= this.limits[i].min) {
            this.initiate_plugin('.shop-items-navigation', {
                containerID : "shop-items-wrapper",
                perPage     : self.limits[i].items,
                midRange    : 8,
                animation   : "fadeIn",
                links       : "blank",
                keyBrowse   : true,
                callback    : function(pages) {
                    var data = {
                        current_page : pages.current,
                        total_pages  : pages.count
                    }
                    self.set_local_storage_data(self.shop_data_key, JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_cluster = function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
    this.set_environment();
    this.initiate_scalable_text();
    this.initiate_placeholder_support();
    this.initiate_iqn_selected_class();
    this.initiate_preview_action();
    this.initiate_plugin(plugin_navigation, plugin_options);
};

var cluster = new Cluster();

});
```

Comment: For a "newbie in JavaScript" your web page uses JavaScript awfully heavily. Most importantly it's completely broken with JavaScript disabled. If it were a "web application", I could understand that, but considering that it's a trivial "content site" and that I can't see any functionality that actually requires JS, I personally find that unacceptable. :-(

Comment: Regarding your script: For a code review it would help to have a short explanation what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Perhaps your opinion it's a bit wrong, how can you say JS isn't necessary ? Do you know of any CSS techniques that could do what the jPages plugin does ? Or how about detecting CSS3 features with Modernizr ? And other fallbacks in JS that some browsers don't support ? And as a simple notice, what browser does not support JS now, 1% of the Earth's population ?

Comment: @RoToRa I think it's pretty obvious what it does for someone who knows JS. Or should I describe what every plugin I use does ? I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting

Comment: Huh? What happend to "as harsh as it would be"? Anyway: I just don't see anything that **requires** JS. All of the basic functionality I can see can be done without any JS, and any "extras" don't require any big "plugins". And fallbacks are great, but you are not using the JS as a fallback, otherwise the site would work without JS. And the most important visitor doesn't support JS. Hint: It starts with "G" and ends with "ooglebot".

Comment: Of course it's obvious what your script does. What I want to know is what **you** want it to do. These can be two very different things.

Comment: @RoToRa I don't have problems with your remarks, what strikes me is that you seem to think that the functionality that I have so far on the site can be acquired without JS, I find that hard to believe :) But if you seem to be so determined that you can make everything with just CSS and HTML, please do so :) I have already done all that can be done with CSS, but of course there may be more I can do, I'm still working on it. And why would I need gbot to index my JS ? I also don't care about where I am in Google's search. And what I want my JS to do is what it already does.

Comment: @RoToRa - Also, I was looking for improvements and clean ups, not someone trying to make me not use JS. I obviously don't know anything about you, neither you about me, so there's no reason for us to fight over an opinion :) I would though appreciate tips on how I can improve my coding and if you think I can achieve what I'm doing without JS I would like to hear about it, as I like CSS more than JS, because after all, what I'm developing is for exercise and for a better understanding of JS :) I hope I haven't offended you in anyway, if I did I'm sorry

Comment: I tried visiting the site in Firefox 12 and got an "unresponsive script" warning at Script: https://raw.github.com/chaoscod3r/less.js/master/dist/less-1.3.0.min.js:8

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use any JS at all. I'm saying it's possible to have the site usable without JS and the functionality I currently see with much less JS. And gbot doesn't need to index the JS, but the content. Currently if a search engine sends someone to your site, they will get the "homepage" but most likely not the content they were looking for (for example the "products"). (NB the site seems to be currently broken. LESS seems to be missing. BTW the JS implementation of LESS should only be used for development not the live site).

Comment: @RoToRa - Yes, sometimes throws that error, seems like it doesn't find the git source of the LESS.js , but there's fallback to local. Anyway, I'm using LESS because the website is under development, I'm not even half way there :) Of course after I developed it, I'll drop LESS and use the compiled CSS, but till then I have to use it because it's much easier to work with. There's a lot of work to do on it, so I'll try using as less JS as possible, but I still need to practice my JS skills too :) You were saying that some features can be meet with CSS, could you tell me what so I can try ? Thanks

Comment: @CheranS - This is the link you were trying to reach : https://raw.github.com/chaoscod3r/less.js/master/dist/less-1.3.0.min.js . Sometimes it throws that error but I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Cluster.prototype.initiate_shop_touch_events` function, the only difference between "left" and "right" is the number that gets added to the current page.  You can reduce duplication by pulling that out into a variable:

```
        var step = (ev.direction == "left") ? 1 : -1;
        var new_page = parseInt(data.current_page + step);
        if(new_page > 0 && new_page <= data.total_pages) {
            $(".shop-items-navigation").jPages(new_page);
        }
```

Comment: I don't get the point here, what if the direction is right ? It actually needs the `ev.direction == "right"` to test which direction the drag event has been fired

Comment: I was assuming that `direction` is only one of two values: "left" or "right".  You can use whatever logic is appropriate to set the value of `step`, but the key point is to reduce unnecessary duplication.

Comment: Yes, I get the logic, only that the drag event can occur to whatever direction you drag your finger along the touch screen :) I'll try this one anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Why is `Cluster` a function? You only instantiate it once, and you don't export anything (as far as I have seen). Use a simple object instead.

If you want to export the `Cluster`, you should not do it onDOMReady, but as soon as your code executes.

```
var Cluster = (function(){
    // private static vars like default_options

    function Cluster() { ... }

    Cluster.prototype = ...

    return Cluster;
})();
// after that, you might instantiate one
jQuery(function(){
    var cluster = new Cluster;
});
```

Also, it might be a good idea to put the onDOMready into the `.inititate_XY()` methods, if they need it. They seem to already use a callback, so it should be no problem - I'm not sure whether that matches your requirements.

Comment: I don't think that using onDOMReady inside the methods might be a good idea, I already have the entire prototype function wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` so there's no need to reuse it, just my opinion. Is it wrong if I'm using it as a function ? What impact will your method have on the website ? Oh, and for now it's only a piece of the entire project, there much more I need to do in fact, but I want to make sure I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

For places where you have an array of selectors (such as `this.headings`), you don't need to loop through each element of the array (never mind that `for...in` with arrays [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)).  Instead, you can use jQuery's [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to create one selector.  This should perform slightly better since there will be less function calls to the plugins.

Example

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_scalable_text = function() {
    var selector = this.headings.join(",");
    $(selector).fitText(1.6);
};
```

Comment: Indeed, this might perform a bit faster. But why looping through an array like I do is not safe ?

Comment: @Roland, did you read the linked SO question?

Comment: I have now :) Seems like a good reason why not, even though in my case I don't think that something like that will occur. Anyway, using jQuery selectors might perform faster :)